# Using A* search algorithm

Tags: algorithm, search, graph, a-star

I am working in graph mining, and for my current research, I am trying to fund the proximity between non-adjacent nodes in the graph.

However, since non-adjacent nodes are ubiquitous, so I want to narrow-down the number of non-adjacent nodes that are related to any node in a graph. Let `a` be a node in a graph, I would like to find the most related non-adjacent nodes to it. For that, I decided to use search algorithm in order to find, for instance, `n-hop` nodes from node `a`.

I initially wanted to use `BFS` and then I decided a more accurate algorithm: **A-star**, so I can determine the start node and have the `g` and `h` functions to be minimized and an upper bound for the cost function to be minimized, as I do not want to specify the target node.

Will that be possible? Because my goal is to find the target node, but not to specify it.

Comment: What's the difference between "find" and "specify"?

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way.  Augment your graph by putting one more vertex in, attached to all target nodes.  Can you do an A* search on that?  If so, then A* search is useful for you.

The critical thing is to have a cost function that puts a useful lower bound on how far you are away from a target node, so that you prioritize the currently most promising line of search over unpromising ones, and switch as soon as it is not quite working as well as something else.